# CryptoJS AES decryption gives wrong result when using same parameter used on encryption

Tags: javascript, aes, cryptojs

Given this code:

```js
var s = "125\xb5\xb5$8"
/* var s = "AAAA" */
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(s)
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(s)

var plain = "Very secret message!"

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plain, key, {
  keySize: 16,
  iv: iv,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
var encryptedb64 = encrypted.toString()
console.log("encrypted:", encryptedb64)

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedb64, key, {
  keySize: 16,
  iv: iv,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

console.log("decrypted:", decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

I get this output (not expected):

```
"encrypted:", "W2dFmOY22wp2W1ayCa1xmk3EwaxG/H+LKkgnADKAYmY="
"decrypted:", ""
```

When changing the key to "AAAA" I get this output (as expected):

```
"encrypted:", "OAmNRtxYfJIFEq4VK4xPievfuXIIfEV+48yHBqVexWI="
"decrypted:", "Very secret message!"
```

**I understand that key & iv should NOT be the same and should NOT be static, but that's not the point here.**

I already have strings encrypted with those parameters and need to decrypt them.  I expected this to work. If the encryption is giving me back a result, then decryption should work when using the same parameters.

Comment: I've replaced the code block with an executable snippet. If you're using a different cryptojs version then please adjust the snippet accordingly: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js

Comment: *0x313235c2b5c2b52438* (9 bytes) and *0x41414141* (4 bytes) are invalid AES keys (and also invalid IVs btw). AES by definition only allows 16, 24 and 32 bytes keys. CryptoJS handles (due to a [bug](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/293)) these invalid AES keys, but produces non-AES compliant results that are not reliable (as your 9 bytes example shows).

Comment: If you pass the key material as passphrase (i.e. as string) and not as key (i.e. as `WordArray`), it will work because CryptoJS then derives a valid key and IV using a key derivation function.

Comment: I totally understand that. I know that those keys are not valid. The thing is I got some data already encrypted with them. Can I do anything to make the decryption also work if the encryption worked?

Comment: Try if it works when you pass the key material as password or when you use the same CryptoJS version that was applied to encrypt the old data. If you don't get anywhere this way, your only option is probably to analyze the source code to find out why decryption works for some invalid keys and not for others.

Comment: I cannot change the way the encryption happened. I already have some data encrypted with that.